# Ruby can't find installed gems windows 10

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When running a script containing the following

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'zip'
```

I am getting

```
`require': cannot load such file -- zip
```

First I have tried to install like this 'rubyzip'

```
gem install rubyzip
```

When looking at the gem env:

```
>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
RUBY VERSION: 2.2.3 (2016-01-26 patchlevel 0) [java]
INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/jruby-9.0.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared
RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/jruby-9.0.5.0/bin/jruby.exe
EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/jruby-9.0.5.0/bin
SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/lucio/.gem/specs
SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/jruby-9.0.5.0/etc
RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
- ruby
- universal-java-1.8
GEM PATHS:
 - C:/jruby-9.0.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared
 - C:/Users/lucio/.gem/jruby/2.2.0
```

in the irb seems like the require works

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'zip'
=> true
```

I also trying to install with bundler after installing

```
>bundle show
Gems included by the bundle:
* bundler (1.12.4)
* rubyzip (1.2.0)
```

but when running my script I get

```
>bundler exec ruby zip.rb
Could not find rubyzip-1.2.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I can also see it in the gem list

```
>gem list -l

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.12.4)
jar-dependencies (0.2.3)
jruby-openssl (0.9.15 java)
jruby-win32ole (0.8.5)
json (1.8.0 java)
minitest (5.4.1)
power_assert (0.2.3)
psych (2.0.15 java)
racc (1.4.13 java)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.2)
rubygems-update (2.6.4)
rubyzip (1.2.0)
```

Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem.
I had Jruby installed along with Ruby, so when installing the gem it will automatically install under the Jruby directory and later won't be found by Ruby removing the Jruby from PATH end variable solved the problem